# Getting a modified range of cells

Tags: excel

I need to apply a function to a range of cells and then getting the modified version of this range.

I need to apply `LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1&" ")-1)` to a range (A1:A6) and get the range back so that `=SUMIFS(B1:B6;A1:A6;"AAA")` works.

Actual problem:
A company sells drugs and they want to know the total sales of a specific drug sold.

`A        |   B 
1  AAA tbl 20x50g   |   3
2  AAA tbl 90x50g   |   4
3  BBB 10% raz 1ml  |   1
4  BBB 2% raz 1 ml  |   8
5  BBB tbl 12x2,5   |   1
6  CCC vet 48x1kg   |   7`

On the next list is a list with only the "generic" name:

   `C    | D 
1  AAA  |  ?
2  BBB  |  ?
3  CCC  |  ?`

I need to get the values in D1.

So far I have came to:
`=SUMIFS(B1:B6;A1:A6;LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1&" ")-1))`
This will compare everything in A1:A6 with the first company (AAA). If it gets a match (A1, A2) it will take the value from the B1:B6 and the answer would be 7.

But I need to apply the "get first word" function
`LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1&" ")-1)` 
to the range A1:A6

EDIT:
My bad. It appears I was trying to reinvent fire by spiting water on wood.
The problem was elsewhere.

The values in B were being produces through

`=IF(AB34=0;"  ";AB34*$Y34)`

and the TRUE clause (" ") messed up the math.

Comment: Drag the formula down? Not sure if I understand.

Comment: @findwindow a little dejavu here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109609/excel-single-cell-multiple-data/38109681#38109609

Comment: @ScottCraner right. I feel like OP's formula works? Edit: also, I don't learn something unless I use it so even though I understand your `sumproduct` each time I read it, it just flies out the window XD

Comment: @findwindow it will not work as you have to pass do the Left(Find()) on the range being searched and SUMIFS does not like doing that.

Comment: @ScottCraner you can't nest `left/find` within `sumif`? Weak XD

Comment: @findwindow you give up some capabilities to get rid of the array formula, so you can use full column references.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am really curious how one goes about coding a compiler.

Comment: @ScottCraner I don't think I remember how to do `index/match` anymore XD

Comment: @ScottCraner just converted one of my `=SUMIF(B:B,G2,D:D)` to `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$85=G2)*$D$2:$D$85)`. The `()` is not readily obvious XD

Comment: This one is a little different as it would need to be `=SUMIFS(B1:B6;LEFT($A$1:$A$6;FIND(" ";$A$1:$A$6 & " ")-1);D1)` which will not work.

Comment: @ScottCraner hm? I mean, I changed one of the formulas in my sheet just to practice XD Bad form to comment here but can't chat XD

Comment: @findwindow aaaaaaah

Comment: @ScottCraner first sumproduct for me ^_^;

Answer (score 2):

You would use the SUMPRODUCT with LEFT(FIND()):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT($A$1:$A$6;FIND(" ";$A$1:$A$6 & " ")-1)=D1)*$B$1:$B$6)
```

[image]

Comment: @findwindow so he/she does.  Fixed it.